# How to call ui object while in an inherited class

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a Qt project. I have a inheritance class which is a Qt Gui class and I want to recover the ui object in the inherited class.

Here is my code :

*inheritance class*

```
namespace Ui {
class AddEditUser;
}

class AddEditUser : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AddEditUser(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~AddEditUser() = 0;

protected:
    Ui::AddEditUser *ui;
}
```

*inherited class*

```
#include "addedituser.h"

class AddUser : public AddEditUser
{
public:
    AddUser();

private slots:
    void on_validationButton_clicked();
};
```

*call in inherited class*

```
AddUser::AddUser()
{
    connect(ui->validateButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(on_validationButton_clicked()));
}
```

I have this error (sorry, it's in french)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33RJj.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a header in AddEditUser.cpp

```
#include "ui_addedituser.h"
or
#include "ui_ADDEDITUSER.h"
```

copy paste this header inside your inherited class and enjoy the access of ui.